# Uploading files to Onedrive using REST API

Tags: rest, windows-store-apps, background-transfer, onedrive

I am trying to upload a file into OneDrive using its REST API. This is what I am trying to accomplish based on documentation available at [OneDrive Rest API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659726.aspx#upload_a_file):

```
POST https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=A300x

--A300x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="HelloWorld.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Hello, World!
--A300x--
```

**This is what I have:**

```
Uri destination = new Uri(string.Format("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/{0}/files?", folder.ID));

BackgroundUploader uploader = new BackgroundUploader ();
uploader.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + account.AccessToken);
uploader.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=\"foo_bar_baz\"");

List<BackgroundTransferContentPart> parts = new List<BackgroundTransferContentPart>();

BackgroundTransferContentPart metaDataPart = new BackgroundTransferContentPart();
metaDataPart.SetHeader("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""+content.Name+"\"");
parts.Add(metaDataPart);

BackgroundTransferContentPart contentPart = new BackgroundTransferContentPart();
contentPart.SetHeader("Content-Type", content.ContentType);
// content is a StorageFile
contentPart.SetFile(content);

response.UploadOperation = await uploader.CreateUploadAsync(destination, parts, "form-data", "foo_bar_baz");
```

**This line below causes an Access violation error and the Windows Store app crashes:**

```
response.UploadOperation = await uploader.CreateUploadAsync(destination, parts, "form-data", "foo_bar_baz");
```

Comment: Have you try putting try/catch blocks around your code to see if any exception is been thrown?

Comment: Exception comes out of a cpp file(background api) and is not caught in (Exception  e) block. There is a try catch around this entire code.

Comment: What about Fiddler or Network Monitor traces?

Comment: I do not think I even reach that stage as this will only create an UploadOperation. Then I will have to use it to start the actual upload. This is windows store app background transfer api call.

Comment: I have always used PUT to upload to SkyDrive/OneDrive. But if you want to use POST, make sure that your body is EXACTLY like they specify including all "-" characters, returns and line feeds.

Comment: Can you please post code for PUT, i can use PUT, but could not figure out the code for it.

Comment: Have you tried to modifying the example projects in https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows to get this scenario working iteratively?

Comment: The scenarios for windows store app at that link uses LiveSDK with LiveConnectClient. I am using the REST API from LiveSDK, there is no matching example that i could find.

Comment: After re-reading your post, it looks like you are trying to pass the access_token as a header instead of adding it to the end of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two `BackgroundTransferContentPart` and only adding the fist to your 'List'.

I think you only need one, something like this:

```
List<BackgroundTransferContentPart> parts = new List<BackgroundTransferContentPart>();

BackgroundTransferContentPart metaDataPart = new BackgroundTransferContentPart();
metaDataPart.SetHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + content.Name + "\"");
metaDataPart.SetHeader("Content-Type", content.ContentType);
metaDataPart.SetFile(content);
parts.Add(metaDataPart);
```

**UPDATE:** Ok, the above code fixed the Access Violation issue. Why you are [getting a 400 error is a mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225335/the-request-entity-body-has-an-incorrect-value-in-the-content-disposition-head).

But another way to upload a file to OneDrive is using the `PUT` method:

```
Uri putUri = new Uri(string.Format("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/{0}/files/{1}",
    "folder.a4fb14adbccd1917.A4FB14ADBCCD1917!32089",
    content.Name));

BackgroundUploader uploader = new BackgroundUploader();
uploader.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
uploader.Method = "PUT";

UploadOperation putOperation = uploader.CreateUpload(putUri, content);
await putOperation.StartAsync();
```

Have you tried `PUT`?

Comment: I have tried this, but this gives a BadRequest (400) error.

Comment: I tried PUT too, it also gives bad request. Does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks, It works with Put. i do not know what went wrong before.