# The request entity body has an incorrect value in the 'Content-Disposition' header. The expected format for this value is 'Content-Disposition:

Tags: onedrive

I have tried multiple HTTP APIs to post a file to OneDrive using the POST method, and I am getting always the same error.

I went to the extreme case of creating my own SSL TCP socket and send the following bytes:

```
POST /v5.0/folder.a4fb14adbccd1917.A4FB14ADBCCD1917!32089/files HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding:
Authorization: Bearer eWciaQ1DBAAUGCCXc8wU/zFu9QnLdZXy%2bYnElFkAAXA4AJqTmiPoOUADOkV98mAdpBZp8SeF0zjYzU4%2bVa0fVR/aWr4X0cHWAzEF7s7HBEABBptxlWcKHEyrgKfbH2YbADpxEjU0gRrOz37WInvPSgFVD8BZ9GtCQwdHh3GUXunbM/Nlqh1TIzELMJYuPEgaEBBWT25f8SoKziZi2kPVlZDPokjJBq2bxrYcAWydDK74ivuiuDGkX4hMpmWZmWtergEybpN2EgObHQa8O3GT2a9ta2hps0ElCv0GkhWG/u1t19/xjokW2dNbbsJ01A9iJkMYXhaMTYg71sGjqzHdXjAJf0hXNg8NiIOTy82MlHqEwCwEyzfXOSGddt0cLkIDZgAACEDf3skftS5%2bWAHGkGlcwFj4DRlrn3/F2DvOZWgyeITjkWfzdx%2b4B8m5olyO5oYKWf77zjVxnUkJ50cIOVCJq/OgnV1kMGB45EExY3%2b3T9JjN0rm91doGnuFGj1m/vuzVN3eP5f3Jr0hMvXbMpzFBImV/c/5SU5esBzA1zas9xt%2bKEi0rriVSqHS4QI4Bps3RN5KpQd4yrNxcTDi%2b9b9AkUVQB%2bxeW5lWGuR5YvaAOHhcePRqNqT2MY7c1zQMoa/C7E63FuOoSdr0KPJbsDKl8aXEt9vT/6A8BK0MnY%2b7MJ1cZaFL%2bhvK0lfI4Z6LJa/3Ayy%2bPt8%2bOc8gNP1Mu/1RCdOT8K1PxwhnvUIE8cnRyI28LUm%2bWUCnurRCNMNBorhZu64JxqOC1EGOja6wNcyI%2bw3TQ1dorDJWN91qENQAxxBMpl1LWdp548kDJcEPwxI4SkXQKnvWcxW1vCZY90SHzruvNmb
Content-Length: 197
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=8381f8b9-b470-43ce-b23b-f13cf5840014
Host: apis.live.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

--8381f8b9-b470-43ce-b23b-f13cf5840014
Content-Length: 9
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="hello.txt"

xxxxxxxxx
--8381f8b9-b470-43ce-b23b-f13cf5840014--
```

And I always get the following bytes back:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 276
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Server: Live-API/18.105.8117.3007 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
P3P: CP="BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo"
X-MSNSERVER: BY3301____PAP073
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-HTTP-Live-Request-Id: API.f06af310-9b49-4cbf-bf71-8c9d79570ec9
X-AsmVersion: UNKNOWN; 18.105.0.0
Date: Mon, 06 Oct 2014 21:37:15 GMT

{
   "error": {
      "code": "request_body_invalid", 
      "message": "The request entity body has an incorrect value in the 'Content-Disposition' header. The expected format for this value is 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"[FileName]\"'."
   }
}
```

All of this happened after I tried to answer [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152636/uploading-files-to-onedrive-using-rest-api/26187551?noredirect=1#comment41124192_26187551).

Any idea?

**UPDATE:** I used the `onedrive-api` tag as [recommended in the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3074fce2-f489-49b1-ad17-f89b7bde533a/onedrive-developer-forum-relocated-to-stack-overflow?forum=onedriveapi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the Content-Disposition header as the first header after the boundary, followed by the Content-Type:

```
--8381f8b9-b470-43ce-b23b-f13cf5840014
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="hello.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8
```

You may need to omit the Content-Length as well to make it work. Pretty fragile really.

Comment: After following your instructions, I was able to POST a file successfully. Unfortunately, HTTP stacks are not that flexible.

Comment: This is how MIME parts works see it in the RFC @section 4 http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2387.html, each section requires its own disposition