# How to upload and create Embed code for Powerpoint to Onedrive using REST API or javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, onedrive

> How to upload and create Embed code for Powerpoint to Onedrive  using  REST API or javascript
>   I am new to Azure can anyone help me to do upload and get embed code for PPT file using REST API or javascript

Comment: Is that you want to know how to upload the ppt to onedrive and share the ondrive item with rest api?

Comment: yes i need to upload using rest api

Answer (score 2):

If you need to upload a ppt to OneDrive via rest API, you can do this using a List or using the PUT method, as described in this thread. [Uploading files to Onedrive using REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152636/uploading-files-to-onedrive-using-rest-api)

You can also use Microsoft Graph. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content?view=odsp-graph-online

As for the second question about embedding, you should be able to use the createLink API to request an embed link.

```
POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/createLink
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "type": "embed"
}
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createlink?view=odsp-graph-online#creating-embeddable-links) for full details.